# Modeling, set to parent or joining objects?

Tags: modeling, parent

I had a hard time deciding whether should I join these pieces to the barrel mesh or just use set to parent.

Also if anyone can explain the difference why should someone use one of these.

[image]

Comment: if you have no reason not to join, like for example the barrel has a modifier that you don't want to give to your rings, then join

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123255/should-i-join-or-parent https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/184033/should-objects-added-in-edit-mode-be-merged-together-or-can-they-exist-as-separa https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14482/what-are-the-benefits-of-modeling-in-one-piece-or-as-separate-parts